# Using Opera, how do I override a bad SSL certificate?

Tags: opera, ssl, certificate

We have an intranet website at work that has a bad SSL certificate.  (I think the problem is the cert server name does not match the host.)  Before you tell me "get a correct SSL cert", I will tell you I have already asked.  They don't care.  You can override the problem in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

I see this error: **Unable to complete secure transaction**.  I reviewed the alert in Opera, checked "Remember my decision", then approved.  However, I still see the error.

How can I continue?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the certificate used by the server? You can get it for example by using OpenSSL: 'openssl.exe s_client -host www.mysslhost.example -port 443'

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this with Opera v11.11 and it remembers this for me for a site that has an invalid certificate on subsequent visits.  (*To simulate the invalidity, I removed the "www." prefix when visiting a web site that doesn't re-direct to fix the hostname.*)

After exiting Opera, then starting it up again, I have to click on "remember" again, but from a security stand-point I believe that this is a smart design decision.

If this isn't working for you, make sure you're using an updated version of Opera (such as v11.11).  Alternatively, if you'd like to share a web site address I'd be glad to browse to it in the hopes of witnessing the same problem (and then I can probably be more helpful).

Comment: I am using 11.50 beta on Linux.  The link is intranet (no external access).

Comment: If you're having to keep accepting the certificate each time you load a page within the same web site, then this is most likely a bug that should be reported to the Opera developers.